# How to get elements from list in structure by pointer

Tags: c++

I have simple struct with int* and I would like to display elems using pointer.
I would like to make something like that

```
for(int i = 0; i<x*y; i++){
        std::cout << parr->elems[i];

   }
```

It shows weird numbers like 126514360, it should show 0s

```
struct MyStruct {
    size_t x;
    size_t y;
    int* elems;
};


MyStruct* createMyStruct(size_t nr, size_t nc, int e = 0){
    int how_many = nr*nc;
    int my_list[how_many];
    for(int i=0; i<how_many; i++){
        my_list[i] = e;
    }
    MyStruct obj;
    obj.x=nr;
    obj.y=nc;
    obj.elems = my_list;
    return &obj;
}

void getElemsFromMyStruct(const MyStruct* parr) {
    int x = parr->x;
    int y = parr->y;


    for(int i = 0; i<x*y; i++){
        std::cout << parr->elems[i];

    }
}

int main() {
    MyStruct* a = createMyStruct(2, 3, 1);

    //it should show elems from MyStruct.elems
    getElemsFromMyStruct(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is very C. I recommend replacing `createMyStruct` with a `MyStruct` constructor and use of a `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique` to manage the memory for `elems`. Eg: https://ideone.com/sJcMC5

Comment: Please don't do manual memory management like this  in new/modern C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `createMyStruct` is returning address of a local variable, created on the stack. Once the function ends, the stack gets unwinded, and the variable is destroyed.

Also, `MyStruct` in the very same function is set to store address of a local array via `obj.elems = my_list`. This also gets removed when the function ends.

I'd recommend reading on stack vs. heap in C/C++. Also, do note that this is much different than managed languages like Java/C#, where a similar approach would work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the `MyStruct` in your `createMyStruct()` function needs to be created using a new pointer, so it doesn't become destroyed. Doing this results in an output of: `100000` with your example.

```
MyStruct* createMyStruct(size_t nr, size_t nc, int e = 0){
    int how_many = nr * nc;
    int my_list[how_many];
    for(int i=0; i<how_many; i++){
        my_list[i] = e;
    }
    MyStruct *obj = new MyStruct;
    obj->x=nr;
    obj->y=nc;
    obj->elems = my_list;
    return obj;
}
```